# Why didn't Hermione use her Dittany on Dobby when he was dying?

Tags: harry-potter, hermione-granger, dobby

She DID have dittany in her bag. She used it to heal Ron. Why didn't she do the same for Dobby???

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97133/why-didnt-dobby-heal-himself?rq=1

Comment: House-elves are magical creatures, and pretty powerful ones at that.  Do we know, for sure, that the dittany is universal across species, or that house-elves don't have resistance to certain types of magic?

Comment: She didn't *have* her bag at that point. AFAIR, at least.

Comment: Have you *seen* the price of dittany these days? Cheaper to just buy another disposable person.

Answer (score 49):

Ron's healing even with the dittany was slow. It also does not seem to help with blood loss, as per the comment about Ron's pallor. 
From Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows:

> "Harry and Hermione half carried, half dragged Ron through the
>   entrance of the tent... Even this short journey had turned Ron whiter
>   still, and once they had settled him on the mattress he closed his
>   eyes again and did not speak for a while."

Dobby was more gravely injured, and likely suffering from internal bleeding and severe blood loss. Hermione was not an experienced healer.  She lacked the skills to do much more advanced magical healing, and likely knew that this situation exceeded anything she was capable of fixing.

Also from Deathly Hallows, **speaking about Ron** but applies to Dobby as well-

> " 'It's all I feel safe doing,' said Hermione shakily. 'There are
>   spells that would put him completely right, but I daren't try in case
>   I do them wrong and cause more damage.... He's lost so much blood
>   already...."

Comment: a point to add, your quote shows ditany does not replenish blood. (might help to emphasis that to further prove your point on dobbys blood loss, and why ditany would be ineffective) but nice find on the quotes +1

Comment: Hermione is clearly risk averse to the point of stupidity. If Dobby is going to die anyway, it doesn't matter how wrong the spells go.

Comment: @Gusdor - are you sure? That's true if the worst consequence of a botched healing spell is just failing to heal. What is she uses some powerful healing spell, fails, and turns him into hyper-regenerating zombie monster?

Comment: @Davor What if the planet explodes every time she tries to pick a lock?

Comment: @Gusdor: you’re driving in a remote area, and come across a motorcyclist who’s hit a tree and appears to be dying of serious internal injuries.  Do you (a) pull out your Bowie knife and attempt emergency surgery, based on a workplace first-aid course and a recent Scrubs re-watch, because really, if he’s dying anyway, it doesn’t matter how badly it goes? or (b) sit with him, talk to him, hold his hand, whatever seems to be able to calm or reassure him as he slips away?

Comment: *"It's all I feel safe doing"* - on the one hand she's well aware of what a bad healing spell can do.  Harry lost a few bones due to a poorly cast healing spell.  On the other hand Dobby was dying.  The worst she could have done is caused him excruciating pain and/or make that pain last longer, or killed him more quickly than he was already dying. As grave as Ron's injury, it wasn't as certain a death as Dobby's, and so I don't know that "safe" can really be considered as the reason she didn't attempt healing magic. She must have known the Dittany wouldn't help in this specific situation.

Comment: Thanks @Himarm, I did update my comments accordingly.

Comment: @AdamDavis, I agree that it seems like it would not make things worse, but if Hermione knew that it was outside of her abilities, trying could, as you pointed out, cause worse or longer lasting pain. I also think that given her mental state from just having been tortured (via the cruciatus curse) by Bellatrix, she was probably not able to react as quickly as usual.

Comment: @thoughtcrimes1984 I agree.

Comment: Do House Elves have blood in their body?

Comment: @PLL honestly? As you said yourself - he's dying anyway, and it was quite easy on Scrubs, what can go wrong? The real question here is, can it be done with only a Swiss Army knife instead of Bowie? ^_^

Answer (score 15):

Dittany appears to be good for helping to heal wounds, not fix internal injuries that require immediate surgery. Healing his skin would have been pointless given that he'd been stabbed in the torso and was likely suffering from a perforated heart/lungs/tomach/spleen/liver, etc. Any of which could be almost instantly fatal

Per [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/features/health-hazards-herbology)

> Sourcing your own potion ingredients can save a Galleon or two, for
> starters. But some herbs could actually heal serious afflictions.
> **Dittany can quickly cure nasty wounds**, and mistletoe berries are
> essential to a well-brewed Antidote to Common Poisons. Very helpful!
>
> <sub><sup>[The highs, lows and health hazards of Herbology](https://www.pottermore.com/features/health-hazards-herbology)</sup></sub>

and

> "Greenish smoke billowed upward and when it has cleared, Harry saw
> that the bleeding had stopped. The Wound now looked several days old;
> **new skin stretched over what had been open flesh.**"
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sup></sub>

Comment: Seems inconsistent at best. If it can heal the muscle and skin on Ron's arm, why not the muscle and skin in Dobby? I know there are many different types of tissue, so I suppose that in theory some of those tissues would not be affected by Dittany.

Comment: Also, in the books, didn't Dobby get hit in the heart/chest? In the related question I linked above, it seems that no one had time to help Dobby, a wound to the heart would cause death much faster than to the stomach (at least in a human)

Comment: "perforated stomach/spleen/liver, etc." The worst possibility is the aorta, assuming anatomy similar to humans. @Skooba That would be nearly as bad as the heart itself.

Comment: @skooba - internal ingestion can heal "cuts and scratches". There's no good indication that it can be used as a substitute for internal surgery

Comment: @skooba - I've amended it to torso since I can't remember where he got stabbed, nor is it especially important

Comment: @MatthewRead  - All the signs point to dittany being most effective on surface wounds and lacerations. Ingestion and internal use can evidently aid the healing process of cuts but it doesn't make you immortal.

Answer (score 10):

The question of whether or not dittany would have been effective is a good one to debate.
However, another thing to consider is the characters' state of mind at the time Dobby got injured. Hermione had just been tortured by Bellatrix, and all of them had just escaped imprisonment and certain death.
So, I doubt any of them were thinking very clearly or logically, especially Hermione.

Also, Dobby's injury was so severe that there was very little time in which to save him. He and Harry landed somewhat far from Ron and Hermione so Hermione wouldn't have immediately known that she could/should look for her dittany in time to save him.